# How to find the number of intermediate nodes in ns2 using dsr

Tags: networking, ns2

I  want to get the number of intermediate nodes between source and destination in ns2 using DSR routing protocol. Can you help me to edit .cc file to obtain the number of intermediate nodes. I want to assign it to a variable. I need that value initially since this value is considered while receiving packet?
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the NS2, every packet has a "common header". You can access this header and read "num_forwards" header field to obtain number of nodes that has forward the packet.